# Regex in C++ with back-references and conditionals

Tags: c++, regex, backreference

I am trying to match words with optional curly brackets around them. I.e. something like "{word}" or "word".

I want to implement it using conditional expressions.

```
({)?(word)(?(1)?}|)

where:
({)?      optional 1st group
(word)    mandatory word
(?(1)}|) if-then-else condition, if the first group was found, it matches the same group again
```

I am not sure about the right syntax for back-references and if-then-else condition in C++.

What I got so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>


int
main()
{
  std::regex re("(\\{)?(word)(\\?(\\1)\\}|)");


  // Possible options
  std::vector<std::string> toMatch = {
    "{word}",
    "{word",
    "word"
    }; 

  for (int i = 0; i < toMatch.size(); ++i)
  {
    std::smatch ss;
    std::regex_match(toMatch[i], ss, re);

    std::cout << i << " : " << ss.size() << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < ss.size(); ++j)
    {
        std::cout << "group >   '" << ss[j] << "'" << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 : 0
1 : 5
group >   '{word'
group >   '{'
group >   'word'
group >   ''
group >   ''
2 : 5
group >   'word'
group >   ''
group >   'word'
group >   ''
group >   ''
```

The first string was not matched at all, the second string matched as it lacks trailing bracket. It seems that conditional and back-referencing mechanisms do not work here.

Comment: ECMAScript regex does not support a conditional construct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I did not find docs stating that clearly. Any chance of getting it working with POSIX (extended regex mode)? Or maybe with boost?

Comment: Yes, it will work  with Boost. But judging by your examples, you regex should be `(\{)?(word)(?(1)\}|)` (you have `(?(1)\1|)` in the description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default ECMAScript regex flavor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) used by `std::regex` (and all other, mostly, POSIX flavors) do not support the conditional construct.

The pattern you have in your code snippet will work in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). Judging by your examples, your regex should look like `(\{)?(word)(?(1)\}|)`.

Comment: I fixed the description. Thanks! Your idea helped a lot. This is the working regex: `boost::regex re("(\\{)?(word)(?(1)\\}|)");`

Comment: @paceholder That is a declaration of the boost regex object. The regex is `(\{)?(word)(?(1)\}|)`, regex is a *string*, a *text*.

Comment: I understand the difference. I have written it for those who need a ready solution for cpp.